# Solving a non-homogeneous system of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Is there a quick method (`DSolve`?) to solve for a system of equations in the form.

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `DSolve` is the way to go.  For better advice, please provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

`X={x1[t],x2[t]}`

`DSolve[Thread[D[X,t] == {{a, b},{c, d}}.X + {e, f}*t], X, t]`

Mathematica gives you a general solution for this.